# store jquery selector into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
$('.add').click(function(){
  runFunction();
  //loop
  //i++
});

$('.deduct').click(function(){
  runFunction();
  //loop
  //i--
});
```

I have the above code, where within the the two `click()` functions, there's only slightly differences, just the increment and decrements different in a loop. I thought of simply storing the selector into an array, is this possible?

```
var arr = ['$('.deduct')', '$('.add')']` ??
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're close; try ...

```
var arr = [$(".deduct"), $(".add")];
```

This will place each of the jQuery objects into the array, referenced as `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple handlers instead:

```
$('.add, .deduct').on('click', function(){
  runFunction();
  //loop
});

$('.add').on('click', function(){
  //i++
});

$('.deduct').on('click', function(){
  //i--
});
```

or

```
$('.add, .deduct').on('click', function(){
  runFunction();
  //loop
  if($(this).hasClass('add'))
     //i ++
  else
     //i --
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can usw the multi selector like arvin suggested.

```
$('.add .deduct').on('click',function(e){
    runfunction();
    if(e.currentTarget() // is add) i++
    if(e.currentTarget() // is deduct) i--
})
```